# Why are we using Z-score to test if $\beta_j$ is equal to $0$ in linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, statistical-significance, linear, z-score

> The book Elements of Statistical Learning while discussing the Linear Regression on page 48-th states that to tests if $\bar{\beta_j} = 0$ we will form the $Z-score$, where $$ z_j = \frac{\bar{\beta_j}}{\bar{\sigma}\sqrt{v_j}} $$ 
>   Here $v_j$ is the $j$-th diagonal element of $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$

I would like to understand why are we performing the $Z-score$ at the first place and how the given formula can be derived?

Comment: Please take another look at the book, in particular you need to distinguish the hypothesis being tested about the unknown parameter ($\beta_j$) for which we use the estimated coefficient in the test statistic ($\hat\beta_j$). As for why we test statistical hypotheses, that is a bit broad to answer here. The derivation can be found in most econometrics textbooks.

Comment: I go through the derivation of this statistic in my answer here, for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344006/