# Calculate joint distribution function of $\hat\beta$ and $\hat\sigma^2$ - regression parameter and variance

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, joint-distribution

I have a following problem:

Consider observations $Y_i, X_{i,1}, . . . , X_{i,p}, i = 1, . . . , n$ modeled as
$Y_i = β_0 + β_1X_{i,1} + · · · + β_1X_{i,p} + ε_i$, where $ε_i$ are assumed to be i.i.d. random variables with Gaussian distribution $N~(0, σ^2)$ and $β_0, . . . , β_p ∈ R$ and $σ^2 > 0$ are unknown model parameters.

What is the joint distribution of $\hat\beta$ and $\hat\sigma^2$ - which are parameter of slope between prediction variable and a target variable and a variance of regression model.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Should this be tagged for self-study so you can hints - rather than answers - so as not to rob your learning?

Comment: This question is covered well at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344006.